# Split Excel File into multiple files based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I am trying to split an excel file into many different excel files with grouped values of a specific column. I would also like each excel file to be named the specific value that is being grouped. EXAMPLE: An employee has 10 records and they all have the employees ID in 'EMPLOYEE'. This employee would have all 10 records on their file and the file name would be their ID. Could I get some help on this? Below is the code I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas
import os

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
column_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
unique_values = df[column_name].unique()

for unique_value in unique_values:
df_output = df[df[column_name].str.contains(unique_value)]
output_path = os.path.join('Lists', unique_value + '.xlsx')
df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value, index=False)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code. If an error is raised please provide the full traceback?

Comment: @Corralien This is what I get -> KeyError: 'EMPLOYEE'

Comment: Welcome. An error is always raised at a line in particular. What line? Regarding [ask@ and [mre], what does df look like, or what should it look like (as text please)? Also, verify code indentation. It is problematic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try this:

```
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas
import os

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
column_name = 'EMPLOYEE'
unique_values = df[column_name].unique()

for n, g in df.groupby(column_name):
    output_path = os.path.join('Lists', f'{n}.xlsx')
    g.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=n, index=False)
```

Comment: The values in "Employee' are integers

Comment: You can wrap n with `str(n)` if you getting some sort of error.